# Spring batch reader doesn't "re-read" when job runs again

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch to gather meta data about files on a local disk. The first time the job runs everything works as expected, however the second time the job executes I'd like it to re-gather that information. At the moment the job restarts and just ends with `COMPLETE` and nothing is processed.

Using a simple reader

```
    @Bean(name = "directoryScannerReader")
    public ItemReader<MediaFileDto> reader() {

        final String directory = "/some/path";

        try {
            return new IteratorItemReader<>(scanService.scanMedia(directory));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stop everything. Unable to read from directory");
        }

    }
```

The `scanService` just returns an array of files for further processing

And I'm launching it every minute from a schedular

```
    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${batch.delay}")
    public void schedule() throws JobExecutionException {
        simpleJobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("date", new Date()).toJobParameters());
    }
```

If I restart the application, the first run will scan the files as expected.

Do I need to pass something in when launching the job? Or is there a more appropriate reader to be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that once your application context is loaded, the `ItemReader` bean is the same for the entire life time of your application. So once it is initialized during application startup, the same bean instance is used in subsequent calls (hence your service is not called again to scan the directory).

The way to fix that is to make the reader step scoped and pass the directory as parameter, something like:

```
@Bean(name = "directoryScannerReader")
@StepScope
public ItemReader<MediaFileDto> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['directory']}") String directory) {
    try {
        return new IteratorItemReader<>(scanService.scanMedia(directory));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stop everything. Unable to read from directory");
    }

}
```

And pass the directory as a job parameter at launch time:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${batch.delay}")
public void schedule() throws JobExecutionException {
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addDate("date", new Date())
            .addString("directory", "/some/path")
            .toJobParameters();
    simpleJobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
}
```

With this approach, you would have a new job instance for each run where the step scoped reader is reloaded each time.

Moreover, passing the directory as a job parameter allows you to reuse the same job to scan different directories if needed, which is not the case if the path is hardcoded in the reader's definition.